# play and stop sound by different button click in same time

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, media-player, onclicklistener

I tried with the following code. My app is a kids' learning app and there I set many sounds. While one button is clicked it's playing, but in the same time, another button click is not working before end of the first sound. I want to release the first sound while another button will click at the same time.

```
public void soreo (View v){
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Soreo);
    final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);
    button.startAnimation(myAnim);
    if (player == null){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soreo);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlayer();
            }
        });
    }
    player.start();
}

public void sorea (View v){
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Sorea);
    final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);
    button.startAnimation(myAnim);
    if (player == null){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sorea);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlayer();
            }
        });
    }
    player.start();
}

public void stopPlayer (){
    if (player!=null){
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.release();
        player=null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop (){
    super.onStop();
    stopPlayer();
}
```

Can you please edit and explain how I will solve the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest stopping the player each time a button is clicked. You may consider the following implementation.

```
public void sorea (View v){
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Sorea);
    final Animation myAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);

    stopPlayer(); // Call StopPlayer here 

    button.startAnimation(myAnim);
    if (player == null){
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sorea);
        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlayer();
            }
        });
    }
    player.start();
}
```

Comment: Glad to know that I could help! Good luck with your learning app for the Bengali language!